# How to provide a free package/membership to users without showing them checkout page and directly activating their membership on my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website, elementor

i want that buyer to get all the perks mentioned in that membership plan for free without showing him/her any checkout page right after when that user clicks on 'FREE PLAN' button given below that plan.

And suggest me some content/information to show in the next page when that user clicks on "FREE PLAN" button.
Plus the name of that user and the particular plan's name he/she selected should be shown to me in dashboard so that i can approve manually, and the way to activate the perks of that plan for that user by myself manually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ In its current state your question has multiple issues _ Just to start with, asking for 'content suggestions' is not permissable here _ Your question is unclear in some other aspects as well. For instance, are you using some kind of WP membership plugin? _ If so, then this information should be in your question. _ From your current score it's clear that you haven't checked out the SO Help Center yet. You should do this and find out a bit more about how this site works & visit specifically the section on what type of questions are acceptable on this site >>> https://

Comment: >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking